# SQL Select with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is get the name of the city with biggest number of orders. Seems simple enough, yet when I run this code (I had to use CTEs), I get only the number of orders, no city name.

```
WITH CityOrder AS
(
    SELECT City 
    FROM Person.Address JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
        ON ShipToAddressID = AddressID
), 
CitiesOrders AS
(
    SELECT City, COUNT(City) AS "NoOfOrders"
    FROM CityOrder
    GROUP BY City
)
SELECT MAX("NoOfOrders") FROM CitiesOrders;
```

I tried to change last line to

```
SELECT City, MAX("NoOfOrders") FROM CitiesOrders;
```

But then, it shows all the cities with their orders. I'm pretty sure I'm not seeing some simple mistake. Any advice?

Comment: It shows because you select City as well. You're telling it you want all Cities and their Max. You properly need to order by COUNT in your CitiesOrders and select TOP 1, then you don't need the third query. Although all of this could be handled in a single query as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know the last one is invalid, I was just showing what I meant, didn't write the whole code with GROUP BY. Expected result is getting ONE city, the one which has the most orders.

Comment: What's the expected result if two cities have the same max count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order your results and take top 1 but with ties in case several cities have same number of orders:

```
...
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
FROM CitiesOrders
ORDER BY NoOfOrders DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
select top 1 * from
(
SELECT City,count(1) as x 
    FROM Person.Address JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
        ON ShipToAddressID = AddressID
group by City
) order by x desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CityOrder AS
(
SELECT City 
    FROM Person.Address JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
    ON ShipToAddressID = AddressID
),  
CitiesOrders AS
(
SELECT City, COUNT(City) AS "NoOfOrders"
    FROM CityOrder
   GROUP BY City
)
SELECT * from CitiesOrders order by "NoOfOrders" desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Product specific answer, for which product? (No dbms specified in question...)

Comment: Too bad op is using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

you write perfect query but a little bit is missing there. You can use your query with `Group by` .

```
SELECT City, MAX("NoOfOrders") FROM CitiesOrders group by City
```